# jQuery .load() returning 404 when html page exists

Tags: jquery, html, firebug

I have one line of code:

```
$(".class").load(variable + ".html");
```

This works fine on my local-host, however on the live site it doesn't work at all. Can anyone explain why this would happen? The pages are all in the same public_html folder on my site.

Firebug gives the URL, and a 404 error. Loading the page manually works fine.

Using `.toLowerCase()` fixed this problem.

Comment: Make sure the file name is correct, your live server may be case-sensitive.

Comment: it would also be helpful if you posted some reference material or links.

Comment: So you're saying that manually typing `http://www.production.com/Filename.html` on the address bar works but doing ajax request to the exact same url gives 404?

Answer (score 4):

If the server is case sensitive you might be checking the correct spelling

```
$(".class").load("Filename.html");
$(".class").load("filename.html");
$(".class").load("Filename.Html");
$(".class").load("Filename.HTML");
```

or whatever you called the file.